# wont store user input in the database using php

Tags: php, mysql

*the problem is only the password is stored but the rest doesnt...* 
*this is the php code*

```
    <?php
         define('DB_NAME','my_db');
         define('DB_USER','root');
         define('DB_PASSWORD','123');
         define('DB_HOST','localhost');

         $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
         $firstname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
         $lastname =isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
         $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
         $bday = isset($_POST['bday']) ? $_POST['bday'] : '';
         $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
         $pass = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
         $submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : null;
         $sql = "INSERT INTO user(fname,lname,email,bday,gender,password)
         VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$bday','$gender','$pass')";
       if(!mysql_query($sql)){
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
       }
        mysql_close();
       ?>
```

*this is the html code*

```
   <form action="connect.php" method="post">
             First name: <input type="password" name="fname">
             Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
             Email Address: <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
             Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday">
             Sex: <input list="Sex" name="gender">
             Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
             <datalist id="Sex">
             <option value="Male">
             <option value="Female">
             </datalist><br><br>
             <input type="submit" value="Sign up!" id="btnsignup" />
        </form>
```

*data types in the table are: fname is varchar, lname is varchar, email is varchar, bday is date, gender is char, password is char *

Comment: Firstly, you need to stop using mysql and change to PDO or mysqli. The mysql interface is deprecated and will soon be removed so there is no point starting to use it now. You also have a SQL Injection vulnerability in your code. There is no user input sanitisation taking place. Please do a `var_dump($_POST);` after you declare `$sql` and post the results.

Comment: Maybe add some closing tags, doesn't seem to be valid HTML to me

Comment: You need to do a `var_dump` of `$_POST`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO array(1) { ["password"]=> string(5) "12341" } i got that. so its only reading the password field. i dont know why it doesnt read the rest.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO these are my datatypes in the table: fname is varchar, lname is varchar, email is varchar, bday is date, gender is char, password is char

Comment: @user2894712 your password can't be `char`. That data type is for **fixed** length fields.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML can only be used with the newest browsers. Try this instead to support older browsers (perhaps you've got one too and that is the problem):

```
<form action="connect.php" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Birthday: <input type="text" name="bday" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
    Sex: <select name="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up!" id="btnsignup" />
</form>
```

You can use `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` in the first line before all other code in your PHP script to check if the POST input from your HTML reaches the PHP.
As a alternative you can check the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, this array will contain GET and POST variables.

Double check if there is other PHP code executed before the one you've posted (redirects, manipulating $_POST vars and so on).
Also check if there are cookies,  $_SERVER or ENV variables set with the variable names you have used.

In normal circumstances your example code should work.

Answer (score -1):

Please check character limit of field in table or field name in  table. I think there is the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Sorry bro but what if this is the problem.

Comment: There is error being reported. There would be a data truncation error.

Comment: But query is executing and password is saving.